# Besides memory and recognition,what are the best arguments against a momentary consciousness?

Tags: atma

Shri Shankaracharya pointed out that memory and recognition prove consciousness is not momentary,but some Nastikas will say that memory is stored in the alaya vijnana storehouse,and that Consciousness is like a flame lighting endless candles.

what are some other good arguments that prove consciousness is eternal?

Comment: where exactly does sankaracharya prove this?? Memory does not 'prove' consciousness. Are people that have lost their memories not conscious? Do people that have alzhiemer's  and not able to recognize who or where they are not conscious? The Atman, the superconscious state, has no awareness of this universe or memory. Memory implies the passage of time, superconsciousness is beyond time. What will it recognize? Recognization implies duality, something outside of It, there is nothing outside of It to recognize...